# Time Index of Lévy Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, levy-processes

Consider (for all $t\geq 0$) a linear time transformation function $\nu(t)=at+b$ with the following properties:

1. $\nu(0)=-1$
2. $\nu(t)$ is an increasing function of the time index $t$ i.e. $a>0$.
3. $\nu(t)$ is a continuous function of the time index $t$.
4. $\nu(t)$ is a 1-1 function of time index $t$.
5. $\nu(t+1)$-$\nu(t)=a$ for all $t\geq 0$.

**Q**: Can we define a Lévy process with $\nu(t)$ as the time index (rather than $t$) or do we need more conditions on $\nu(t)$? In other words, I would like to see the possibility of defining $\{Z_{\nu(t)};\nu(t)\geq -1\}$, where $Z_{\nu(t)}$ is a Lévy process.

P.S. I originally asked this question on http://stats.stackexchange.com, but I couldn't find an answer, so I posted it here.

Comment: Sorry, why do you list all these five properties which are trivial consequences of just saying:  let $\nu(t) = at -1$ with $a>0$? (Note, your 'property' 1 is equivalent to saying $b=-1$).

Comment: These are the properties that I think $\nu(t)$ should have e.g I listed $\nu(0)=-1$ to indicate that the starting time index is $-1$ and not $0$ as usual.

Comment: Ok the confusing thing is: either you are asking whether it is possible to make the linear time transformation, or whether, in general, it is possible to make a time transformation for any $\nu$ satisfying 1-5.  The way you write it makes it sound like you are just asking about the linear transformation...

Comment: why $v(0)=-1$? in Brownian motion, the time index starts with $0$. Should not it be $v(0)=0$ instead

Comment: @Frank: I don't want to make the linear transformation. I just wanted to know if I can use this linear transformation to define a Levy process.

Comment: @user3001408 :  I agree that most of the times B.M. is defined with starting time index of $0$. But I don't think this is necessary and we can define it on $[-1,T]$ rather than [0,T].

Comment: yes you can, provided the relation between $v(t)$ and $t$ is one-to-one mapping...But why do you want to inject extra complication, what you want to achieve with such transformation?

Comment: Thanks, I had to transform the original time transformation using this type of linear transformation due to the computational purposes. Working with the original time transformation is very time-consuming.